# Group by values ignoring commas

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains rows that, mostly, have the name of a single country assigned to each row. Unfortunately, at some point, the “country” field had multiple values which were separated by a comma. Most of the rows now have a single value, but there are residual commas left in the some of the fields. For instance, some rows that pertain to Afghanistan have “Afghanistan” and some have “,Afghanistan”. My current SELECT query treats those values as two separate groups. I am not allowed to fiddle with the database to get rid of the commas.

What do I do to have my SELECT query to disregard the commas and group the  countries values together. As an added complication, there are a few rows that have multiple country values, which, again, I can’t edit. Ideally I would like to exclude those entirely from the SELECT query (as well as rows that have a negative value in another field.

Example data of what my current query gives me:

```
,Afghanistan    66
,Albania    1
,Angola 25
,Bangladesh 2225
,Bolivia    824
,Bosnia 1
,Bosnia And Herzegovina 291
,Bosnia and Herzogovina 181
,France, Germany 1
Afghanistan32
Albania 3
Bangladesh  132
Bolivia 295
Bosnia and Herzegovina  79
Botswana    2
```

Here is my query:

```
/* Group by country and count instances selecting the resources has a positive number in the ref ID  */ 

SELECT field3 "Country", COUNT(field3) FROM `resource` WHERE ref > 0 GROUP BY field3;
```

Comment: "I am not allowed to fiddle with the database to get rid of the commas." RUN AWAY. NOW.

Comment: @Strawberry So of us don’t have that luxury . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(field3, ",", "") AS Country, COUNT(field3) 
FROM `resource` 
WHERE ref > 0
GROUP BY Country;
```

Comment: Thanks  @Rahl The result is one row which is a count of all the records. What I get if I removed the `GROUP BY` statement. The `GROUP BY` seems to be ignored . . .

Comment: Try GROUP BY REPLACE(field3, ",", "");